# Set locale and timezone for all cases in Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian

I'm trying to cover all cases of setting the locale and timezone in a Dockerfile. I've written the following but it feels like it's overkill:

```
# Set for current session
ENV LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" \
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8" \
    LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8" \
    TZ="UTC"

# Install locales
    # Uncomment en_US.UTF-8 locales in /etc/locale.gen file
RUN sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen && \
    # Generate new locales from /etc/locale.gen file
    locale-gen && \
    # Set system locale for login shells
    echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile && \
    echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile && \
    echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile && \
    # Set system timezone for login shells
    echo "export TZ=UTC" >> /etc/profile && \
    # Set system locale for non-login shells for root
    echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    # Set system timezone for non-login shells for root
    echo "export TZ=UTC" >> ~/.bashrc
```

As you see I'm trying to cover (for bash ofc):

- current session
- login shells for all users
- non-login shells for all users

Is the above too overkill? Incorrect? Is there a more proper way to cover all cases?